# django - how to bind records of table with calculated count values from another table

Tags: python, sql, django

In my application I have a list of trainings. One field on this list should display number of booking for each of training.
To show what I mean I prepared SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM club_training a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT training_id, count(*)
FROM club_booking
group by training_id) b
ON a.id = b.training_id
```

Could you give me some advice how to do it in django?
I used `Booking.objects.all().values('training_id').annotate(booked_amount=Count('training_id'))` in my code, but the result is that all count values for all trainings are displayed for each training on the list. Should be displayed one count value which is apropriate for each training.

[image]

views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    """Home Page with list of trainings"""
    template_name = 'club/training_list.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['trainings'] = Training.objects.filter(state="A", training_date__gte=now).order_by('training_date', 'start_time')
        for each_training in context['trainings']:       
            each_training.diff = each_training.availability - each_training.counter
            each_training.counter = Booking.objects.all().values('training_id').annotate(booked_amount=Count('training_id'))
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Training(models.Model):
    """Class for plan training"""
    STATE = (
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('I', 'Inactive'),
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey('TrnDesc')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey('Instructor')
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(default='00:00:00')
    availability = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=15)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE, default='A')
    training_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name

class Booking(models.Model):
    """Data of people which book fitness classes"""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    training = models.ForeignKey('Training')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.training.name.name
```

training_list.html

```
{% extends 'club/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Fitness Classes</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Join Us</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br></br>
    {% regroup trainings by training_date as date_list %}
    {% for date in date_list %}
        <div class="panel panel-default">


            <div class="panel-heading">{{date.grouper|date:"l, d F o"}}</div>


            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 20%">Training name</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%">Training description</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Instructor</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Start time</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">End time</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Left</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Test_counter</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Actions</th>
                </tr>


                {% for training in date.list %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{training.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.name.desc}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.instructor}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.start_time|time:"H:i"}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.end_time|time:"H:i"}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.diff}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.counter}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'book' training_id=training.pk%}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button></a></td>
                </tr>

                {% endfor %}    
            </table>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So if i'm getting it right, you want to get **training id** and the **count of booking objects** of all the groups of booking, grouped by training_id. Have I understood it correctly, or do you want something else?

Comment: On my training list I want to display count of booking objects for each training (for each training_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for each_training in context['trainings']:       
        each_training.diff = each_training.availability - each_training.counter
        each_training.counter = Booking.objects.filter(training_id=each_training.id).count()  # just modify this line
    return context
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [answer]

Comment: @annlii, this is one of the answer. But technically if there are `n` training objects in `context['trainings']` , then you are making `n` number of `Booking.objects.filter(training_id=each_training.id).count()` queries to your database. So if the value of `n` goes up, you'll be able to see using **DjangoDebugToolbar** that its taking way too much time for your page to load. Whereas the equivalent query you wrote for SQL, was just one query returning you everything you wanted.

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi thank you for noticing that problem. For now it is ok for me, but later I will probably have to come up with sth more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach from the other direction: `each_training.booking_set.count()`

Also, I'm not sure it fits your database goals, but if I understand what you are looking for, you could set it up like this:

**models.py**

```
class Training(models.Model):
    ...
    <fields>
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name

    @property
    def counter(self):
        return self.booking_set.count()

    @property
    def diff(self):
        return self.availability - self.counter
```

Like this, the values can go directly from the model to the template.

The only problem that I can see with this is that I think it prevents these fields from being part of a queryset. For example, `Training.objects.filter(counter__gt=0)` won't work. If you need that, I think you'll still have to find an opportunity to save and update the value in the database, [possibly using a signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/), that way you don't have to save the value over and over again every time the view is called.

It also looks like you could use a manager to handle some of the logic you are doing in the view:

**managers.py**

```
from django.db.models import Manager

class Active(Manager):

    def by_date(self, date)
        Training.objects.filter(state="A", training_date__gte=date).order_by('training_date', 'start_time')
```

Then you can add the manager to your model (being sure to preserve your vanilla manager):

**models.py**

```
from .managers import Courses

class Training(models.Model):
    ...
    <fields>
    objects = models.Manager()
    active = Active()
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

And now you can distribute all the information with a slim ListView.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class HomePageView(ListView):
    """Home Page with list of trainings"""
    template_name = 'club/training_list.html'
    context_object_name = "trainings"

    def get_queryset(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return Trainings.active.by_date(now)
```

I'm not familiar with some of the things you are doing in the template, but everything should work the same way it does now.

Or maybe I'm way off, but hopefully its some good food for thought :)

Comment: Defining a `@property` doesn't stores the value of that property in the database and hence is **calculated** at the time of its requirement. So technically using `def counter` will only slow down the page load at is it calculate the count value for each object at the time of page load. Hence making it too slow if the number of objects and hence the calculations are too many.